# React Native: How to display: 'none' a specific button in flatlist

Tags: react-native

I'm making a flatlist that has a delete button inside each data. I want to show a data's name outside the flatlist and do the `display: 'none'` the button only for that line of the list to disable the delete button. Any way I can do this?

My renderItem code:

```
//----------------Render flatlist------------------
function renderItem({ item }) {

    return (
        <View style={styles.renderBox}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{ width: 230, fontSize: 17, fontWeight: 'bold' }} > {'=> '} {item.certificateName}</Text>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeCertification(item.id)} >
                    <Icon name='check-circle' size={40} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>  </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => DeleteCertificate(item.id)} >
                    <Icon name='times-circle' size={40} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

the display of my flatlist: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6zbH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that an item can have a prop called `isHidden` (or something like that). In `renderItem` add a conditional to check isHidden isnt true:

```js
function renderItem({ item }) {
    if(item.isHidden)
    // return empty view
    return <View />
    return (
        <View style={styles.renderBox}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{ width: 230, fontSize: 17, fontWeight: 'bold' }} > {'=> '} {item.certificateName}</Text>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeCertification(item.id)} >
                    <Icon name='check-circle' size={40} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>  </Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => DeleteCertificate(item.id)} >
                    <Icon name='times-circle' size={40} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

in `DeleteCertificate` you would update your list to an item having isHidden

```js
function DeleteCerticate(id){
   //...
  //im assuming your list is name DATA
  const ixToHide = DATA.findIndex(item=>item.id == id)
  if(ixToHide >= 0)
    DATA[ixToHide].isHidden = true
}
```